# Extracting between two strings with sed until the first occurrence

Tags: sed

Can someone explain why I am getting different outcome while using the same command? I have 2 c++ files:

1. 1st one(ax.h)

```
int iseven(int a);
int sum(float a, int b);
```

2. 2nd one(ax.cpp)

```
//Definicija

int iseven(int a) {
    if (a%2==0){
       return 1;
    else
       return 0;}
   
   
float sum(float a, int b) {
    return a + (float)b;
    
}
```

Why is it when I use the command:

```
sed -n '/iseven/,/}/p' ax.cpp
```

My output only does what I want and it print the text between `iseven` and the first occurrence of`}` ->

```
int iseven(int a) {
    if (a%2==0){
       return 1;
    else
       return 0;}
```

But when I use the same command(`sed -n '/iseven/,/)/p' ax.h`) on my 1st file(ax.h), it prints everything out:

```
int iseven(int a);
int sum(float a, int b);
```

And what I was expecting was `int iseven(int a);`

Comment: based on your comments with Barmar I'd suggest updating the question with more samples of different formats that could occur in the 2 files (eg, extra lines, nested parens/braces, etc); will all file names end in `.h` or `.cpp`? for `.h` files will you always be looking for an ending right paren **and** semicolon (`)` + `;` - possibly with whitespace between?)? for `.cpp` files will you always be looking for an ending right brace (`}`)? how many files do you plan on searching (in a comment you mentioned an array of file names)?

Comment: please also provide details on what you'll be searching for ... a single function name in all files? a list of functions across all files? something else? the idea is to look at the bigger picture ...

Comment: After reading all the comments from Barmar, I see how multiple brackets could cause the trouble, luckily i don't have that issue, because all the files I have to sort don't have multiple brackets, my assignment is to find where the function occurs in a directory, so ```./script.sh Project iseven ```and then I get over all the files that have that, I did figure out all that already, the paths, the files.. basically what he suggested solves my problem, still I would like to know how to make it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use
`/start/,/end/` as the address in a `sed` command, it starts searching for `end` on the next line after the match of `start`. So you can't use a pattern range when the end pattern is on the same line as the start pattern.

You could just use `/iseven/p` to match just those lines in `ax.h`, unless you need to allow for declarations to be spread over multiple lines. If you need to handle both single-line and multi-line declarations, there might be a way using the hold space, but I'm not an advanced enough `sed` user to show how to do it.

Comment: Why are you using a range? Just use `/iseven/p`

Comment: My original code is actually checking for tons of c++ programs in a directory, so instead of a file, I'd have an array of files, in this case it wasn't working so i just used it as an example, what I'm saying is, it might be in the same line, it might not be. So having both of them work is important to me.

Comment: But you have different sed commands for `.cpp` and `h` files. One searches for `}` and the other searches for `)`.

Comment: Does that make a difference? In the .h files im searching for function implementations, so iseven until the first closed bracket )

Comment: It makes a difference because you have different expectations in the two types of files.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect the code for `.cpp` to work. What if there are multiple `}` in a function?

Comment: In fact, your `.cpp` code is wrong. You have an unmatched `{` after `if`.

Comment: `sed` is simply the wrong tool for something like this. What you really need is something that matches balanced brackets.

Comment: pluse-uno for tech support (-;

Comment: It's not me who wrote c++ programs, but my assignment is to sort them, I see how this is wrong tho, thank you